# Allow only image selection on ng-image-compress

Tags: angularjs, image, ng-image-compress

I am using ngImageCompress module for compressing image files. I got reference from https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress this repository.

Now when file open dialog opens, it will allow users to select any type of file when file type selected as "All Files". I already used

```
accept="image/*"
```

attribute on ng-image-compress.

Please suggest so that user will not be able to selected other file types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got solution for this issue.

Just write following code snippets in

```
element.bind('change', function(evt)
```

within angular-image-compress.js file.

```
var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         ////Check selected file type, if file type is image then allow else give message. 
         var file = this.files[i];
         var fileType = file["type"];
         var ValidImageTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"];
         var count = $.inArray(fileType, ValidImageTypes);
         if (count < 0) {
              alert("Only JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF files are allowed");
              return;
         }
         .... 
         .... 
   }
```